# Moved jquery.js and now I get Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(…)

Tags: javascript

I moved the jquery.js to local and back via SFTP. but know I get 54 different: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(…)

Comment: this is the page: http://52.51.220.53/

Comment: well sounds like you do not have jQuery on your page.

Comment: http://52.51.220.53/wp-content/cache/minify/02c2f.js

Answer (score 1):

You are minifying your javascript, via a Wordpress plug-in i assume, when accessing it:

```
http://52.51.220.53/wp-content/cache/minify/02c2f.js
```

Your server is returning a 500 internal error, meaning no javascript is being loaded on the page.

Comment: the file is there and it is not changed in any way

Comment: and yes I'm using W3 Cache

Comment: @luben if you open that file in your browser you will see the 500 i'm talking about - basically your JS is NOT getting to the browser. Investigate why the 500 is happening.

Comment: thank you. I'll try my best!